# CS50 caesar part 1. What does return 1 do in the code below?

Tags: c, cs50

Why is the `return 1` necessary in the code below? Is this to stop the loop from 'looping' after '1' cycle since it will go ON forever if the Boolean expression is false?

```
while (argc != 2 || isnumber(argv[1]) == false)
{
    printf("Usage: .caesar key\n");
    **return 1;**
}
```

Can you explain this step by step?

Comment: Honestly it looks like they could have just used an if-statement

Comment: Thanks and you are definitely right as everyone have said. Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The statement should actually be `if` statement instead of `while`, as you execute the program once (with some input) and you cannot change it on-the-run.

`return 1` (as well as `EXIT_FAILURE` macro) means that there was an error in the program, which in your case is bad number of arguments.

`return 0` (and `EXIT_SUCCESS` macro) means that program finished without any errors.

Comment: You should note the normal usage `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);` and `exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);` in your discussion compared to the `return` statement. Why you can `return` a value from `main()`, but need to use `exit()` if within all called function, etc...

Comment: Thank you! That totally makes sense. Sorry my up-vote cannot be reflected since I don't have enough "reputation" yet since I am still new here but just want you to know that I appreciate the answer a lot and the additional information. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

The return 1 is necessary as if you provide the wrong number of command line arguments, it will return 1 to indicate a failure, which is to stop the program. You actually do not need the while loop, you can actually do

```
if (argc != 2 || isnumber(argv[1]) == false)
{
  printf("Usage: .caesar key\n");
  return 1;
}
```

You can also use other numbers bigger than 0 for failure and return 0 is for success.

Comment: Yes, thank you as others have pointed out as well. Rookie mistake I guess. Appreciat eyou all.